telegram bot to trigger share_to window with checkbox
I am using python-telegram-bot module to create a InlineKeyboardButton called invite. I would like the user to click the invite button then a share_to window with checkbox showing up like this .
But when I use switch_inline_query, what I get is like this .
async def handle_start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
"""Handle the /start command and send an inline keyboard."""
keyboard = [
    [InlineKeyboardButton("Play Now", callback_data="play_now")],
    [InlineKeyboardButton("Follow X", callback_data="follow_x"),
     InlineKeyboardButton("Join Troops", url=f"https://t.me/{BOT_USERNAME}")],
    # Use switch_inline_query to open the "Share to" window
    [InlineKeyboardButton("Invite", switch_inline_query="Invite your friends!")]
]

reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

await update.message.reply_text(
    "good luck!\n\n",
    reply_markup=reply_markup
)

I am wondering how to achieve the share_to window with checkbox?
